# Density of distance from center of circle to a chord

Tags: probability-theory, circles, density-function

`Given two random points on the unit circle, A and B, define X to be the perpendicular distance from the center of the circle to the chord. Find the density function of X`

**My attempt:** I was given a hint that because of symmetry we should fix one point and consider only the other point random. The definition of random was not given, so I fixed a point at $(1, 0)$ and let the other point be defined by its angle with the positive axis $\Theta\sim \text{Uniform}[0, 2\pi)$.

From this, I derived 
$$X=\left|\cos\left(\frac{\Theta}{2}\right)\right|$$
and manipulating $\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)$ and differentiating gave me a density function of 
$$f_{X}(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}},\qquad 0\leq x < 1$$

However, this seems unintuitive and incorrect to me. Why would the density approach infinity as the distance $x$ approaches 1? Have I made a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is okay.

For $x\in[0,1]$ we find: $$P(X\leq x)=P\left(-x\leq\cos\left(\frac{\Theta}2\right)\leq x\right)=P\left(\arccos(x)\leq\frac{\Theta}2\leq\arccos(-x)\right)=$$$$\frac1{\pi}(\arccos(-x)-\arccos(x))=\frac1{\pi}(\pi-2\arccos(x))=1-\frac2{\pi}\arccos(x)$$

Taking the derivative you found correctly the density of $X$.

> "Why would the density approach infinity as the distance $x$ approaches 1?"

Well, why not?

Notice that $\frac{P(1-\epsilon<X\leq 1)}{\epsilon}\to+\infty$ if $\epsilon\downarrow0$ which is in accordance with a density approaching infinity.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused how you knew to inspect the limit of $P(X > 1-\epsilon )/\epsilon \to\infty$. Is this derived from an intuitive observation or did you simply observe this from the cdf? What is a similar situation where finding this limit (or proving it doesn't exist) would be relevant?

Comment: You said "this seems unintuitive". I just went searching for some justification. This only for you because it does not provoke my own intuition at all. The inspection of the limit is not more than inspection of derivative of CDF in neighborhood of 1 (so actually the value of the density near 1).